DataGrid - commit edit immiditately
I have a CheckBoxColumn that the visibility of another element is binded to. However, the edit to the property in the dataviewmodel is not commited before the user changes rows. Is there no way to commit the edit as soon as the checkbox is checked?
   <controls:DataGridCheckBoxColumn
       Binding="{Binding MultipleChoice.Value}"
       Header="MultipleChoice"
       Tag="MultipleChoice" />


This is a known issue and is very unlikely that it will be fixed:

https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/3438
https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/3566

Instead you can use the DataGridTemplateColumn.
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MultipleChoice">
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MultipleChoice.Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- If you can specify the data type:
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        -->
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>

Also check this doc.

If this helped, please accept it as the answer so we can close this session. : )
